# file i/o with Java

Tags: java, file-io

So I have a background in c++ and I am trying to learn java.  Everything is pretty similar.  I am having a problem thought with file i/o.    So I am messing around and doing really simple programs to get the basic ideas.    Here is my code to write data to a file.   My code makes a file, but when I open the file it is empty and does not contain the string I told it to write.

```
 package practice.with.arrays.and.io;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;

 public class PracticeWithArraysAndIO 
 {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    //Declaring a printWriter object
    PrintWriter out  = new PrintWriter("myFile.txt");

    out.println("hello");
 }

 }
```

Comment: Try putting `out.flush();` after `out.println("hello");`

Comment: Did you try to google your question ? http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/

Comment: Actually you want to close the writer before exiting: `out.close();`

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses.  I know I am like a total newbie at java.  Thanks for the kind responses.

Comment: Why is my question getting voted down.  I needed help so I wrote it.    Can I not ask simple questions on this site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is buffered and needs to be `flush()`ed to be written to a file.

```
package practice.with.arrays.and.io;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class PracticeWithArraysAndIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("myFile.txt");
        out.println("hello");
        out.flush();
    }

}
```

But you don't need to flush explicitly because that will happen anyway when you `close()` the writer, which you ought to be doing.

```
package practice.with.arrays.and.io;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class PracticeWithArraysAndIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("myFile.txt");
        try {
            out.println("hello");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

}
```

But you also don't need to close explicitly because `PrintWriter` implements `AutoCloseable`, so you can use Java 7's automatic resource management:

```
package practice.with.arrays.and.io;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class PracticeWithArraysAndIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("myFile.txt")) {
            out.println("hello");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much I really appreciate it.  I added the stuff you told me and it worked.   I just totally spaced and forgot I had to close the file.   Thanks for the help.